# Using pybedtools with a BEDTools static binary

Tags: python, bedtools

I want to use `pybedtools` in a python program that I am compiling into an executable with `pyinstaller`. The intent is that this executable will contain all of the necessary files to run the program, including shipping `BEDtools` as a binary. However, when I try to run pybedtools using the code below, I get a NotImplementedError, implying that pybedtools doesn't work with this approach. Is it possible to run pybedtools wrapping a binary like this? Is `set_bedtools_path` not the right tool to use for this problem?

Example code:

```
import os
import pybedtools

pybedtools.helpers.set_bedtools_path(os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'bedtools.static.binary'))

a = pybedtools.example_bedtool('a.bed')
b = pybedtools.example_bedtool('b.bed')
print(a.intersect(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to accomplish this task using a static binary. However, an equivalent (although perhaps slightly less elegant) solution was to download the .tar archive from the bedtools website, compile it from source, include the entire directory as data, and use `pybedtools.helpers.set_bedtools_path(...)` to point the package to the bedtools/bin/ folder.